# Increase reputation bar hover size

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, reputation-graph, tooltips

I noticed today when I was viewing my profile, looking at my reputation, that if you hover over a bar on your "reputation graph" the tooltip shows the date and the exact reputation earned like so:

[image]

However, if you have only earned a very small amount of reputation proportional to another day on your chart, the bar is very small (as it should be); except the "hoverable" area also becomes extremely small (and by extension hard to hover over). I suggest increasing the hover area to the size of that "entire day" regardless of reputation earned that day to increase usability:

[image]

If you hover anywhere in the red box the tooltip would appear. Obviously not a big issue but I think it would be useful.

EDIT: In response to Benjamin Gruenbaum discussing possible development overhead, I disagree. Here's a fiddle I put together in five minutes demonstrating this change: (observe the behavior of the left-most bar)

http://jsfiddle.net/A4QUR/6/

Comment: Fair request, simple to do. +1 from me. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yeah, this was simple, so I did it.  Also added a subtle hover to the container's background color, to hopefully help indicate there's a tooltip.

[NOW GIMMIE THE REPS!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OADJl-CVDo0) :)

Comment: * this is only on Meta right now - it will be rolled out everywhere later.

Comment: Awesome! If this can be also applied to the [big graph](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3/jarrod-dixon?tab=reputation&sort=graph) it would be even awesomer... ;)

Comment: Reps given. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Knock knock... who is there? [bug with Opera](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/185619/152859). :)