# Reputation chart in Opera has a display bug

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, reputation-graph, opera

Last item in the user reputation chart summary in Opera jumps to new line. I am using Opera Version 12.15 and Windows 7 64-bit operating system, zoom level is 100%.

See the screen shot:

[image]

Comment: Zoom level is 100%?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd, yes, zoom lvl is 100%.

Comment: Well, there was a [recent change](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185498/152859) probably the dev didn't check with Opera.

Comment: Oh `inline-block` and those pesky source spaces...

Comment: Weird, I tried with the same setup and couldn't reproduce it.

Comment: The problem also occurs on my desktop: XP, 1024*768, Opera 12.15

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd hmm, I actually did check Opera 12.15 and IE 10, and I didn't see any issues.  Still don't on Win8.

Comment: @Jarrod weird. Did you check the OP's profile? Maybe something there causing this, not general bug

Comment: We can repro on Win7, but not on Win8... Win7 appears to be applying a larger `margin-right`.  Looking for a workaround.

Comment: @JarrodDixon I don't think it's the margin, but how the browser decides to render the `font-size: 0px` whitespace between the elements since the graph bars are `inline-block`. I'm not sure that there's an easy solution that will make it behave exactly how the other browsers currently do, though.

Comment: Seen on Vista, Opera 12. One workaround might be to have no spaces between `</div><div` @jar

Comment: @JarrodDixon did you have chance to look into it? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made some changes to our CSS - tested in current Opera and v. Next. With you in the next build.